# Installing Mandriva ROSA rocket launcher in Ubuntu KDE

Tags: rpm

I have a desktop computer in which I have installed the Mandriva 2011, it has a new application menu launcher like Unity, and is called ROSA Rocket launcher. I feel that this a better application launcher than the default KDE launcher.

My question is, Is there anyway to install it in Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved how to install Mandriva ROSA Launcher in Ubuntu and using it as a Plasmoid widget. For more details please see the below link.

http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2012/02/mandriva-rosa-launcher-for-kubuntu.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you'll have to do some dependency digging. The actual conversion of an RPM to a DEB is fairly simple.

1. Download the RPM. In this case [I found it here](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/linux/MandrivaLinux/official/2011/x86_64/media/main/updates/) (takes a while to load for obvious reasons).
2. Install the `alien` and `fakeroot` packages.
3. Convert:

   ```
   fakeroot alien rosa-launcher-0.34.5-1.1-mdv2011.0.i586.rpm
   ```

Now you can install it. Whether it works or not is up to you having the right dependencies installed and it being compatible with a different version of KDE. You can [see the core dependencies here](http://pkgs.org/mandriva-2011/mandriva-main-updates-i586/rosa-launcher-0.34.5-1.1-mdv2011.0.i586.rpm.html) but remember these are Mandriva packages - their Ubuntu equivalents might have a different name.

You might just be easier downloading the source for the package and compiling it under Ubuntu but that's going to require finding out even more dependencies and then learning how to compile one of these things.

Comment: Well ROSA launcher is installed without any dependency problem after converting it into a deb file, but I can only launch it as an application with Window border and not as a Menu popup  ... nor as an Item in plasma widgets. How can I make it default application launcher ?